# Generating a similarity matrix from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, similarity

I have a df

```
id    val1    val2    val3
100    aa      bb      cc
200    bb      cc      0
300    aa      cc      0
400    bb      aa      cc
```

From this I have to generate a df, something like this:

```
     100  200  300  400                    
100    3    2    2    3
200    2    2    1    2
300    2    1    2    2
400    3    2    2    3
```

Explaination:  **id 100** contains  `aa,bb,cc`   and **200** contains `bb,cc,0`

There are 2 similar values.

Therefore in my final matrix, the intersection cell for  **index-100** and **column 200**, **2** should be inserted.

Similarly for **id 200-** values are `bb,cc,0`  and that for **id 300** - `aa,cc,0`

Here the similarity is **1**, therefore in my final matrix
the cell corresponding to **200(index)-300(column)** should be inserted with **1.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some preprocessing. First, `set_index` to `id` and get rid of `0`s, we don't need them.

```
df = df.set_index('id').replace('0', np.nan)

df    
    val1 val2 val3
id                
100   aa   bb   cc
200   bb   cc  NaN
300   aa   cc  NaN
400   bb   aa   cc
```

Now, use a combination of `pd.get_dummies` and `df.dot` and get your similarity scores.

```
x = pd.get_dummies(df)
y = x.groupby(x.columns.str.split('_').str[1], axis=1).sum()    
y.dot(y.T)

     100  200  300  400  
id                   
100    3    2    2    3
200    2    2    1    2
300    2    1    2    2
400    3    2    2    3
```

Comment: I think the zeros should be handled like any other value. Notice that your output is a bit different

Comment: @AndreyF From this I understood: `Similarly for id 200- values are bb,cc,0 and that for id 300 - aa,cc,0; Here the similarity is 1` that 0s should not be counted

Comment: @jezrael I tried that... it gives me an incorrect answer for other columns.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks... it's clear OP was inconsistent with formulating their output

Comment: @jezrael Thanks. I've added it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i donot want 0's to be counted. Sorry my mistake, 0's can be considered as NAn

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the data into sets and then intersect them:

```
df = df.replace('0', np.nan)
c = df.apply(lambda x: set(x.dropna()), axis=1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[len(x.intersection(y)) for x in c] for y in c],columns=c.index,index=c.index)
```

The desired output will be:

```
     100  200  300  400
100    3    2    2    3
200    2    2    1    2
300    2    1    2    2
400    3    2    2    3
```

Comment: In your answer, 0s are counted, so 200-300 is 2, when it should be 1. Clearly OP's output is inconsistent.

Comment: fixed. Now I drop '0' values