# Filter, rolling window and drop duplicate in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as below and I would like to filter every 3 rows in the Column FisherID and then drop the duplicate species in column SpeciesName. Actually, I can do it manually by use the code below, but it take a lot of time since I have many rows. So, I would like to know whether we can use another way and faster then this (e.g. rolling window..). Many thank in advance.

My current code:

```
site1=df.query('FisherID == [1,2,3]'); site_1=site1.groupby(["FisherID", "CountryName"])["SpeciesName"].apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates())

site2=df.query('FisherID == [4,5,6]'); site_2=site2.groupby(["FisherID", "CountryName"], as_index=True)["SpeciesName"].apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates())
```

here is my Data:

```
FisherID  CountryName   SpeciesName
10        Vietnam       Barbonymus altus
11        Vietnam       Barbonymus gonionotus
12        Vietnam       Barbonymus schwanenfeldi
7         Thailand      Anguilla marmorata
8         Thailand      Bagarius yarrelli
9         Thailand      Bagrichthys obscurus
4         Lao           Albulichthys albuloides
5         Lao           Amblyrhynchichthys truncatus
6         Lao           Anabas testudineus
1         Cambodia      Amblyrhynchichthys truncatus
2         Cambodia      Acanthopsis sp.1
3         Cambodia      Achiroides melanorhynchus
4         Lao           Albulichthys albuloides
5         Lao           Amblyrhynchichthys truncatus
6         Lao           Anabas testudineus
4         Lao           Albulichthys albuloides
5         Lao           Amblyrhynchichthys truncatus
6         Lao           Anabas testudineus
7         Thailand      Anguilla marmorata
8         Thailand      Bagarius yarrelli
9         Thailand      Bagrichthys obscurus
10        Vietnam       Barbonymus altus
11        Vietnam       Barbonymus gonionotus
12        Vietnam       Barbonymus schwanenfeldi
```

Comment: If use `df = df.drop_duplicates(["FisherID", "CountryName","SpeciesName"])` get what you want?

Comment: If you want to keep only one of the records with given CountryName, you have a number of options to pass to `df.drop_duplicate`:
1) a list of columns to check ['CountryName']
2) `keep='first'` keeps the first element for each duplicate, `keep='last'`keeps the last one

Comment: @jezrael Sir, can you please help me in solving this type of problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441705/generating-a-similarity-matrix-from-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I see it, but  not so easy - but I try ;) But please remove comment, because people in SO hate it  ;)

Comment: @SRingne - but I think iy is nice question, so get answer. You can improve it by some code, what you try.

Comment: Thank a lot both you for helping. 

Maybe my table that I provide here is a bit simple than the real one. Last time, I tried with drop_deplicate, but I lose a lot of info. So, Is there any way to do filter for every 3 row? Thanks again

Comment: If use your currect code there is different output like `df = df.drop_duplicates(["FisherID", "CountryName","SpeciesName"])` for rows with `1,2,3,4,5,6` ? It seems not.

Comment: @jezrael: Could you please kindly help me with the above question? many thanks

Comment: @Vanna - `filter for every 3 row` - it is a bit unclear - do you need replace `1,2,3` to `a`, `4,5,6` to `b`... ? Or not?

Comment: Or do you need new column - for first 3 rows `0`, for second `3` need `1` and similar to end of df?

Comment: @jezrael: I would like to filter every 3 row window (e.g. 1st filter is from 1-3 and 2nd filter is 4-6....). And, then remove all the duplicate species in the colomn "SpeciesName" for each filter. Sorry that my question is not clear.

Comment: @Vanna - I test it again and with your data `df = df.drop_duplicates(["FisherID", "CountryName","SpeciesName"])` get same output as `site1=df.query('FisherID == [1,2,3]'); site_1=site1.groupby(["FisherID", "CountryName"])["SpeciesName"].apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates())

site2=df.query('FisherID == [4,5,6]'); site_2=site2.groupby(["FisherID", "CountryName"], as_index=True)["SpeciesName"].apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates())` for `1,2,3,4,5,6`. Why is not possible use `drop_duplicates` only? Real data are different as sample?

Comment: @jezrael: Yes, I tried your code again and now it is fine and highly appreciated for your kind help in this. Have a nice day!